# How to get all the integers present in the string?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using the following code, to get the integers present in a string. But this will give the first occurrence of an integer. Just print 14. I need to get all the integers. Any suggestions.

```
Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
            Matcher makeMatch = intsOnly.matcher("hello14 hai22. I am here 4522");
            makeMatch.find();
            String inputInt = makeMatch.group();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern intsOnly = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher makeMatch = intsOnly.matcher("hello14 hai22. I am here 4522");
String inputInt = null;
while(makeMatch.find()) {
    inputInt = makeMatch.group();
    System.out.println(inputInt);
}
```

Comment: This will not print first match.Use `do..while` instead.

Comment: It will.  Using `do...while` will throw an exception if there are no matches.

Answer (score 4):

Hint : Don't you need to loop to get all the digits?

Comment: @mre You're right. I keep forgetting about homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> allIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(matcher.find()){
    allIntegers.add(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this nice tutorial on Regular Expressions in Java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html):

> To find the first match of the regex in the subject string, call myMatcher.find(). To find the next match, call myMatcher.find() again. When myMatcher.find() returns false, indicating there are no further matches, the next call to myMatcher.find() will find the first match again. The Matcher is automatically reset to the start of the string when find() fails.

I.e. you can use the following code:

```
while (makeMatch.find()) {
  String inputInt = makeMatch.group();
  // do something with inputInt
}
```

Comment: Or see the "official" Java Tutorial [Regular Expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) tutorial.